# How can I store multiple usernames and passwords with the iOS keychain?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, keychain

I'm currently using Apple's KeychainWrapper to store a single username and password, but i'd like to add the functionality of being able to login to different accounts, and switching between them in my app.

Is it a matter of storing identifiers for different keychains in a plist, and then re-initializing the keychain each time I want to change account? or is there a better approach to this? maybe a NSMutableArray of keychains?

Thanks,
Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to check the open source SFHFKeychainUtils class.

It is extremely simple, you just need to call one method to add (or update):

```
+ (BOOL) storeUsername: (NSString *) username andPassword: (NSString *) password forServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName updateExisting: (BOOL) updateExisting error: (NSError **) error;
```

...one method to get the stored password:

```
+ (NSString *) getPasswordForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error;
```

...and one method to delete:

```
+ (BOOL) deleteItemForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error;
```

[It is available in GitHub](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security/). You just need to drag and drop the classes and import the Security framework to your project.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, i'll check this out! The site says SFHFKeychainUtils is deprecated, should I be using https://github.com/ldandersen/STUtils/blob/master/Security/ instead?

Comment: If they say it's deprecated, so indeed would be good to start with  this one you linked, Nick. Don't forget to vote up if it helped and/or accept the answer if it solved your problem.